# Force www prefix using an SSL VirtualHost setup

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, redirect

Running Apache/2.4.7.

I seem to be having some trouble forcing a `www` prefix for one of my SSL domains.

The following patterns should redirect to: `https://www.foo.com`

- `foo.com`
- `www.foo.com`
- `http://foo.com`
- `http://www.foo.com`
- `https://foo.com`

It's worth mentioning, I also want to preserve any URI that may have been requested, eg. `foo.com/bar` => `https://www.foo.com/bar`

So here's the, relevant, current code in my `foo.com.conf` file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.com
    ServerAlias *.foo.com
    RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*) https://www.foo.com/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName foo.com
    ServerAlias *.foo.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I would appreciate some guidance here.

Comment: your :443 virtualhost doesn't do any redirects.

Comment: Ohh, elaborate? I tried something like that but only achieved a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jonah's snippet worked well, but I ended up utilising [mod_macro](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_macro.html) to avoid repetitive code.

```
<Macro ServerAliasesRedirect>
    ServerAlias foo.com
    ServerAlias *.foo.com
    RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*) https://www.foo.com/$1
</Macro>

<Macro SSL>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/foo.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/foo.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/foo.com.ca-bundle
</Macro>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Use ServerAliasesRedirect
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    Use SSL
    ServerName www.foo.com    
    # ...directory stuff and so on...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    Use SSL
    Use ServerAliasesRedirect
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `ServerName` directive in both port 80 and port 443 virtual hosts.

Add a similar redirect match directive as in the port 80 virtual host to the port 443 virtual host.

Make another port 443 virtual host with

```
ServerName www.foo.com
```

Ensure this virtual host appears and is processed before the other port 443 virtual host.

This virtual host is where users will land after being redirected. So put other appropriate configuration here.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias foo.com
    ServerAlias *.foo.com
    RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*) https://www.foo.com/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.foo.com
    # various directives as appropriate for live service to users
    # important to place this before the wildcard VirtualHost below
    # which will match all subdomains 
    # not matched by a preceding VirtualHost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAlias foo.com
    ServerAlias *.foo.com
    RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*) https://www.foo.com/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, although I only partly follow. Perhaps you could supply a refined code snippet?

Comment: I was unable to restart apache, given your example. Here's the errors:
Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] ((null):0)
Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.

My SSL cert and Directory stuff is specified in the first *:443 VirtualHost

Comment: The certificate needs to be available in both virtualhosts